# Spring JPA is failing to autowire/inject bean beyond unit test, what have I done wrong?

Tags: spring, jpa

I promise I have spent many hours reading documentation on spring.io, trying quick-start tutorials etc. but I just cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have also looked through similar questions on here, and tried proposed solutions (where relevant). I'm sure it's something ridiculously simple, so I'm sorry for having to ask.

My repository:

```
@Repository
public interface SomethingRepository extends CrudRepository<Something, Integer> {

}
```

The configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EntityScan("com.where.they.are") //changed for anonymity - assume correct
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.where.they.are") //changed for anonymity - assume correct
public class DatabaseConfigurationInTest {

}
```

Here is some class where I'm trying to inject my repository (it fails), it's always null:

```
public class SomethingDAO{
@Inject
private SomethingRepository somethingRepository;
}
```

But in this unit test, it works just fine, injection and everything.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = DatabaseConfigurationInTest.class)
@ActiveProfiles("local")
public class SomethingRepoTest{
    @Inject
    private SomethingRepository somethingRepository;
```

Comment: `SomethingDAO` has to be a Spring bean in order for CDI to work. Is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To @Predrag Maric point , your class `SomethingDAO` could be annotated with @Service and make sure it`s package  is reachable by  componentScan

```
@Service
public class SomethingDAO{
@Inject
private SomethingRepository somethingRepository;
}
```